# Find the equation of the common tangents

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the equation of the common tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ and $x^2=4by$.

My Attempt :

$y^2=4ax$ is the equation of parabola with focus at $(a,0)$

$x^2=4by$ is the equation of parabola with focus at $(0,b)$

The equation of the tangent to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is 
$$y=mx+\dfrac {a}{m}$$
$$m^2x-my+a=0$$

The equation of the tangent to the parabola $x^2=4by$ is:
$$x=m'y+\dfrac {b}{m'}$$
$$(m')^{2}y - m'x+b=0$$

Comment: You'd need $m'=1/m$ surely?

Comment: in the last equation there should be  $$-m^{'}x$$ not $$- m^{'}y$$

Comment: @LordsharktheUnknown, how?  Please elaborate

Comment: I assume that it easy for you to calculate the slope of the tangents using Calculus [maybe I am wrong]. Then equate them and solve the tangent points.

Comment: The dual conics are $-4a^2Y^2+4aX$ and $-4b^2X^2+4bY$, which intersect in $(0,0)$ and $(1/\sqrt[3]{a b^2},1/\sqrt[3]{a^2 b})$, which means that the line at infinity and $1/\sqrt[3]{a b^2} x+ 1/\sqrt[3]{a^2 b} y +1=0$ are common tangents.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland That seems like it should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @amd,  why $m=m'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A(at^2,2at)$ and $B(2bu,bu^2)$ be the points on $C_1:y^2=4ax$ and $C_2:x^2=4by$ respectively.

Equation of tangent of $C_1$ at $A$:

$$\frac{x}{-at^2}+\frac{y}{at}=1 \quad \cdots \cdots \: (1)$$

Equation of tangent of $C_2$ at $B$:

$$\frac{x}{bu}+\frac{y}{-bu^2}=1 \quad \cdots \cdots \: (2)$$
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    -at^2 &=& bu \\
    at &=& -bu^2 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

On solving,

$$t=\frac{1}{u}=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{a}}$$

The common tangent is

$$-\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{ab^2}}-\frac{y}{\sqrt[3]{a^2b}}=1$$

$$\fbox{$\sqrt[3]{a}\, x+\sqrt[3]{b} \, y+\sqrt[3]{a^2 b^2}=0$}$$

Comment: how did you write equations 1 and 2?

Comment: Equation of tangent for conics $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ at the point $(x',y')$ is given by

$$\fbox{$ax'x+h(y'x+x'y)+by'y+g(x+x')+f(y+y')+c=0$}$$

Then transform the equations into ***intercept form*** for easy comparison

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the tangent to the parabola  $y^2=4ax$ is

$$m^2x-my+a=0$$

this equation also satisfies $x^2=4by$ because you want a common tangent thus it touches the 2nd parabola at some point

$$m^2x-m\frac{x^2}{4b}+a=0$$
find x put it back in  $x^2=4by$

you will get a point P follow the same procedure for the 2nd line get point Q  then find the line joining P AND Q

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right tack! According to your work
$mx-y+\dfrac {a}{m}=0$ and  $x-m'y-\dfrac {b}{m'}=0$ are equations of the same line which implies that their coefficients are proportional (we assume that $a$ and $b$ are not zero):
$$\frac{m}{1}=\frac{-1}{-m'}=\frac{\dfrac {a}{m}}{-\dfrac {b}{m'}}.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{cases}
m=\dfrac{1}{m'}\\
m=-\dfrac{am'}{bm}
\end{cases}\implies 
m=-\frac{a}{bm^2}\implies m=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}
$$
and, by after solving with respect to $m$, we find that the the common tangent is 
$$-\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}\, x-y-\dfrac{a}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}}=0$$
that is
$$y=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}}\, x-\sqrt[3]{a^2b}.$$

Comment: what should I do further?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... You have system with two equations to solve with respect of $m$ and $m'$

Comment: what do we have to calculate?  $m$ and $m'$?

Comment: Yes, they will depend on the given data $a$ and $b$.

Comment: so we'll have two equations of tangent?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... I revised my answer. Any further doubt?

Answer (score 1):

You’re almost there. You’re looking for the *common* tangents—the two tangent equations that you’ve written down must describe the same lines. Assuming both parabolas are nondegenerate, multiply the first equation by $b$ and the second by $a$ to get $$m^2bx-mby+ab=0 \\ m'^2 ay - m'ax + ab =0.$$ Equate coefficients to produce the system $$m^2b = -m'a \\ m'^2a = -mb$$ from which $$m^4(b/a) = -m$$ We know that the common tangent isn’t horizontal or vertical because the only place where that could happen is at the origin, but the two parabolas intersect there. Therefore, $m = -\root3\of{a/b}$.